# Conditional compilation in Haskell other than using CPP

Tags: haskell, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

The [CPP](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/utils.html?highlight=ifdef#input-syntax) extensions allows conditional compilation, e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
#ifdef DEBUG
-- some debug code
#endif
```

It works fine, of course, but it's quite clumsy and non-idiomatic. Is there really no other mechanism to achieve conditional compilation?

(The specific case where I really would like to use it is the [Text.Megaparsec.Debug.dbg](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.0.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Debug.html) function. The parse trail it produces is really useful, but the source code gets littered with `#ifdef`...`#endif` noise which makes it all rather unreadable. A wrapper function at the top would remove most of the noise, but I'm wondering nonetheless.)

Comment: I'd say that CPP is the common way to achieve conditional compilation. I'd also say that CPP is, at the moment, the idiomatic way. Another option is Template Haskell that could be used, in some cases, to that purpose, but I've never seen it used as such.

Comment: Another potential option would be to use Backpack. Put a debug function in a module signature, then write two internal libraries with implementations: one which is a no-op, another which delegates on the true debug function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lightweight solution is to only use CPP once to define a boolean which can then be used in regular Haskell code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define debug True
#else
#define debug False
#fi
```

or a macro if you don't even want the debug code to go through typechecking.

---

Another way to do conditional compilation without CPP is to change the source of modules at the package level, though I don't know any real example of this.

Create two modules with the same name `debug/Debug.hs` and `nodebug/Debug.hs`, both exporting, for example, a boolean `debug :: Bool`.

In the package configuration, add a flag to select between `debug/` and `nodebug/`.

```
flag debug
  description: debug mode
  default: False
  manual: True

library
  ...
  if flag(debug)
    hs-source-dirs: debug
  else
    hs-source-dirs: nodebug
```

Now you can build the library with `-f +debug` to enable debugging.